# Orthonormal basis of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, vector-spaces

I am asking if somebody knows how to do or is aware of the following construction:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be given, then take an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Then, there are maps $\Phi_A:=[A,\cdot]: \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$

Now one could look at the subspace spanned by all those maps
$V:=\{[A,\cdot]; A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}\} \le L(\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}).$

This space carries the natural Frobenius inner product and I would like to know if somebody has ever constructed an ONB for the subspace $V$. So is there a known explicit constrution of an ONB of $V$ (depending on $n$, of course)?

Comment: Why the votes to close? The space $V= \{ {\rm ad}_A \colon A \in M_n({\bf C})\}$ is well-defined and if we think of each ${\rm ad}_A$ as a Hilbert-Schmidt operator then it's not obvious to me if one has a nice o.n. basis for V (beyond what one would get from applying Gram--Schmidt, of course).

Comment: @YCor I agree that the map $\Phi: M_n({\bf C})\to V$ has its kernel spanned by the identity matrix, and so you've given an o.n. basis for $\ker(\Phi)^\perp$. What I was a bit puzzled by was what kind of o.n. basis we got for $V$ given that it lies inside $HS(M_n({\bf C}))$, but I admit I haven't given it much thought

Comment: @YCor I do not understand this comment, you describe how to give a basis for the space of trace free matrices. How does this give rise to an ONB for $V$?

Comment: Sorry I was confused, but still it's an exercise. The point is to compute the bilinear product $(A|B):=\langle\Phi_A,\Phi_B\rangle$ in the canonical basis. It yields: $(E_{pq}|E_{pq})=2n$ for $p\neq q$, $(E_{pp}|E_{pp})=2n-2$, $(E_{pp}|E_{qq})=-2$ for $p\neq q$. So indeed it boils down to finding an orthonormal basis for the hyperplane $\sum x_i=0$, but for the scalar product $(e_i|e_i)=2n-2$, $(e_i|e_j)=-2$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: @YCor please forgive me for being stupid, but I have still problems understanding what you mean. 1.) You say bilinear product, but your $(A|B)$ comes from a scalar product, so it should be sesquilinear, no? 2.) you introduce $e_i$, what are those? By the way, it seems odd to me that for $n=1$ we get $(e_1|e_1)=0$ according to your comment, so $e_1=0,$ is that correct? I do not doubt that my question has an easy answer, but would you mind turning your comment into a proper answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @LukaTinska I can't guess from your question whether by Frobenius inner product you mean the bilinear one $\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij}$ or the sesquilinear one $\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\overline{b_{ij}}$ but it amounts to the same since I did the computation on a basis and this only involved real terms. And it's normal that for all $n$ we get, for the identity matrix $I=\sum_{i}E_{ii}$, $(I|I)=0$ since $\Phi_I=0$ (in particular for $n=1$ $(E_{11}|E_{11})=0$).

Comment: in my previous comment (starting with "Sorry...") I forgot to write that all other products $(E_{pq}|E_{p'q'})$ are meant to be zero, i.e., it's zero as soon as ($p\neq q$ or $p'\neq q'$) and $(p,q)\neq (p',q')$.